# Detect when iOS breadcrumbs are used to return to app

Tags: ios, swift

I can't find information about how to detect when the iOS breadcrumbs are used to return to the app. I am looking to call a function on the controller when the view is active again specifically when this breadcrumb is used (Our use case being when location has been enabled externally).

I have tried using `viewDidAppear` but this isn't called. Is it possible? I find it unusual that this isn't called.

To be clear the breadcrumbs I am talking about are [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this method on Appdelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application { 
}
```

then send a notification to your viewcontroller you want to handler.

Comment: That does the trick. Good suggestion. Hopefully this functionality will be refined as it seems quite removed to do a simple task.

Comment: do you know how to do this in swift?

Comment: @Josh: this is swift function:     func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {        
    }